# Use Ada code in Android

Tags: java, android, compiler-construction, code-reuse, ada

Is there any possibility to use old Ada code in Android?

I have an old script written in Ada and it would be great if I could just use that code in Android directly (via NDK or JNI etc). Is this possible? Or should I rather port the code?

Here are some links I found but I don't really understand in what extend they answer my question:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Platform/VM/Java

http://code.google.com/p/javada/

http://code.google.com/p/jgnat/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNAT

**Added:** http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada/browse_thread/thread/4cb1f8d1c17d39a8?pli=1

Comment: Please elaborate on _old script_. How old? How big? See also this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada/browse_thread/thread/4cb1f8d1c17d39a8).

Comment: Using an Ada/bytecodes cross-compiler is a slight possibility, but it's hard to say how well it will work, especially given that the Android version of bytecodes is a hair non-standard.  Lots of hurdles to overcome, at the very least.

Comment: The source is from 1998 and the code is about 870 kB.

Comment: A minor point: code written in Ada, or in any compiled language, is not commonly referred to as a "script". It would more commonly called a "program" or perhaps a "library", depending on what it is. The word "script" more commonly applies to programs for interpreted languages, such as a shell, Perl, or Python. (The dividing line between "script" and "program" can be vague.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it unlikely that you could just compile the code with some particular cross-compiler, drop it on an Android, and have it work, unless it was perhaps some kind of toy program.

That said, [DragonLace](http://www.dragonlace.net/) provides GNAT AUX, a FreeBSD-hosted port of the GNAT Ada compiler for Android.

Comment: Thank you! So you would recommend to port the code to Java instead of using a cross-compiler, right?

Comment: Uh, well, no. *My* preference, as an experienced Ada developer, would be to use the DragonLace compiler and treat it as a rehosting effort. But that's just me.

Comment: Okay, but DragonLace seems to be available for Android 2.3.3+ only. And unfortunately, I have almost no experience with Ada. So cross-compiling the script so that it runs on Android may be very difficult. Perhaps it's even easier to learn a bit Ada and port it. What do you think?

Comment: Um, no offense, but I think you may be in over your head.  870K of source code is no small amount, and learning "a bit" about Ada is unlikely to give enough of a knowledge base to port it to another language.  (Presumably you know Java, in your opinion how successful would someone be who had almost no experience with that language learning a bit about it and attempting to translate 870K of Java source to, say, C?) There's no quick solution, either learn Ada *well enough* if you want to handle the translation yourself, or learn enough Ada *well enough* to effectively work with a cross-compiler.

Comment: Thank you, looks as if I had to learn Ada "well enough" in all cases :) So I'll do that.

Comment: @Marco: Glad to hear that!  :-) And don't hesitate to ask questions here or comp.lang.ada if you need help. <plug>Also, the [Ada sub-reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/ada) has links to news, info, and examples about Ada.</plug>

Comment: Thank you for your help! But in general, one can say that Java and Ada are quite similar, aren't they?