# Ada-Coded Android Apps Via Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, ada

Having read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795601/use-ada-code-in-android)

I was wondering if the use of Eclipse would be feasible for people attempting to put Ada-coded apps on their Android phones . . .

Adacore has already made an Ada add-on for Eclipse.

Has anyone tried this successfully ?
If not has anyone ideas on its viability ?

I know writing these apps in Java is the normal and anticipated way. But Java is not the first language to some of us. And I'd like some cool practice on my Ada coding.

Comment: Seems not. Apparently, the Android virtual machine is run on Dalvik bytecode which is different to Java bytecode seemingly.

Comment: You don't have to compile Ada to Java or Dalvik bytecode. You can compile it to native executables.

Comment: Elaborate ! It is an Android app originally source-coded in Ada that I'm trying to make. That which is a 'native executable' to my PC + Windows is not necessarily a 'native executable' to my (or anyone else's) mobile phone CPU + Android system.

Comment: Well, there is an Android cross-compiler: http://www.dragonlace.net/gnataux/armv7/ - it should produce native executables for android and your mobile phone.

Comment: Yeah. Just been reading into that one. It seems to be the sole option as of now. Thankee, pilgrim.

Comment: This avenue comprises using something like Virtual Box to hold a FreeBSD op system which has facilities allowing cross-compilation of Ada, Fortran and C/C++ source into binaries runnable on Android. Live Android can also be operated on a PC using Virtual Box. I followed YouTube instructions on getting this into my PC and it goes okay, though the touchscreen simulator is a bit flighty ! Will report later on progress with FBSD and GNAT AUX.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the dragonlace compiler can be used to run your Ada code on Android. I did some experimenting with this as well.
You may want to have a look at my Ada for Android page here
http://rveenker.home.xs4all.nl/Ada%20on%20Android.html
The trick is to include the native code inside your apk so you can install it as a regular app.